# Spring MVC + Session Management

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-mvc

I am developing a web application with the spring framework and Hibernate as the ORM. I want to create a register and login page. On login, A session should be created for the particular user(like sending a cookie etc). Since I am new to spring, I am not aware of how to get this done. Can some one give me a good tutorial on this? Thanks!

Comment: What does Hibernate has to do with your question? Aren't you confusing HTTP sessions and Hibernate sessions? Those have nothing in common.

Comment: Hi. I am not aware of the details. Hence i mentioned all the details. How do i Create a HTTP session in spring?

Comment: Creating a session is done by the underlying JEE web container, as part of the servlet specification contract. Spring MVC is built on top of the standard servlet specification, so there is nothing special you need to do to create a session. As for tutorials, there are loads. Just search for "spring mvc tutorial", adding whatever extra technology buzzword you need and you are sure to find something.

Answer (score 6):

A HTTP session has nothing to do with Hibernate, and not much to do with Spring MVC. It's part of the standard Servlet API.

A session is started as soon as you call `request.getSession()`, (`request` being an `HttpServletRequest`) or as soon as a JSP is executed (unless you have specifically configured it to avoid making it start a session).

You just have to assume that the session is there. It's started automatically when you get it from the request, if it doesn't exist yet.

Once a user is authenticated, you can store some user information in the session. But unauthenticated users also have a session.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out, it describes pretty much how you should manage security with Spring

http://www.springsource.org/spring-security/

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out this is nothing to do with Hibernate, take a look at the [getting started](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-getting-started) docs for Spring Security

Answer (score 0):

You can use @SessionAttributes({"form"}) to keep the form data or you can have HttpSession variable in controller signature and spring will provide you with servlets session object. Check http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html (section 15.3.2.3)